# How do enable my Infowindow?

Tags: carto, infowindow

Why is my infowindow disabled on the data set I uploaded from NYCOpen Data or the sample data on CartoDB?

Comment: did you turn them on? http://docs.cartodb.com/tutorials/infowindows.html

Answer (score 1):

Infowindows are disabled by default when you create a map. As mapBaker says in the comments, you need to enable them by going to "Map view" and accessing its toolbar. The third option "infowindow", will allow you to enable/disable/customize both your infowindows on click and on hover.

Please, remember that the infowindows are independent per each layer, so you'll need to add them per each of them. Also, if you're inside the editor and you're working in a specific layer, the interactivity will be disabled for the other layers. If you open the public URL of your map you'll be able to check the results.